# Are mongodb backups made automatically?

Tags: mongodb, backup, cloud-foundry, developer-console, swisscomdev

We use two mongodb services and there is now a backup button in the swisscom developer console. Do we have to do the backups manually with this button or are further backups made automatically? if yes, when and how often?

Comment: As this is a question about database administration on a particular cloud platform, and not directly or indirectly about programming, it really belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ rather than here.

Answer (score 2):

We make automatically backups, but only for desaster recovery. We don't provide this backups to customer.

So please trigger in Developer Portal backup for you. Other option is to automate backup with `mongodump` or the Filter API.

There is an [API endpoint](https://api.lyra-836.appcloud.swisscom.com/api-doc/#!/Service_Instances/post_custom_service_instances_service_instance_id_backups) for triggering backups.

> API Docs | Custom Extensions | Swisscom Application Cloud Filter for
>   Cloud Foundry (CF) Cloud Controller (CC) API. Implements Swisscom
>   proprietary extensions

```
POST /custom/service_instances/{service-instance-id}/backups
```

> Creates a backup for a given service instance

See for more Info [Service Backup and Restore](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide-sc/services/backups.html) in docs.developer.swisscom.com

> Create Backup To create a backup, navigate to the service instance in
>   the web console and then to the “Backups” tab. There you can click the
>   “Create” button to trigger a manual backup.
>
> Note: Backups have to be triggered manually from the web console.
>
> Be aware that you can only keep a set number of backups per service
>   instance. The actual number is dependent on the service type and
>   service plan. In case you already have the maximum number, you cannot
>   create any new backups before deleting one of the existing.
>
> It may take several minutes to backup your service (depending on the
>   size of your service instance).
>
> Restore Backup You can restore any backup at any time. The current
>   state of your backup will be overwritten and replaced with the state
>   saved to the backup. You are advised to create a backup of the current
>   state before restoring an old state.
>
> Limitations You can only perform one backup or restore action per
>   service instance at a time. If an action is still ongoing, you cannot
>   trigger another one. You cannot exceed the maxmimum number of backups
>   per service instance