# Create, restore, and download MongoDB backups automatically on Swisscom Application Cloud

Tags: swisscomdev

We can create create backups from the [Developer Portal](http://developer.swisscom.com) for MongoDB, but I'm wondering if this is exposed in any other way through the CLI?

Also, how can I access the backup to inspect it on my machine for example?

Comment: What UI do you mean? Compass? Atlas? Some 3rd party cloud solution? if it is hosted service, it should have an API, we can help you find it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CLI tool for making backups: [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) (in the mongodb-org-tools package)

See also https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are two CLI keystrokes to backup and restore

*Backup*

```
   Mongodump backupPath
```

*Restore*

```
   Mongorestore -d databasename backupPath
```

Ex- mongodump C:/user/desktop/backup

mongorestore -d   DB1  C:/user/desktop/backup/DB1

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can't do anything outside of the UI. As per their docs: https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide-sc/services/backups.html

Comment: see my anwser. There is an API, but yes you can't download your data from portal. Please also search #swisscomdev there are many similar questions and even GitHub projects to the backups without portal (directly to own S3 instance).

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for Service Instance backups and restores (the interface you see in developer portal). See other question [Are mongodb backups made automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452950/are-mongodb-backups-made-automatically). There is even a [CLI plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47550368) to automate Developer Portal backups. Try it with `cf install-plugin -r CF-Community "Swisscom Application Cloud"`.

You can't download the backups to your local computer. For that you you need to use `cf ssh` tunnel and `mongodump/mongorestore`. There is a guide to migrate Swisscom MongoDB to other DB provider (like your own computer), see [here](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/migrate-mongodb-to-kubernetes-based-mongodb.html) for the exact commands.